# Call array variable from solidity contract in web application

Tags: solidity, web3js, blockchain, ethereum-wallet-dapp, ethereumjs

I have declared one array inside solidity contract like "**uint256[] public machineList;** " and initialize the values of that array inside the constructor.

But when I call that array inside js usgin web3 mentioned as below :

```
AssetContract.deployed().then(function(contractInstance) {

    let getMachineList = contractInstance.machineList;
    alert(getMachineList);
});
```

It is returning below output in getMachineList variable:

```
    function () {
  var instance = this
  var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments)
  var tx_params = {}
  var last_arg = args[args.length - 1]
  if (Utils.is_object(last_arg) && !Utils.is_big_number(last_arg)) {
    tx_params = args.pop()
  }
  tx_params = Utils.merge(C.class_defaults, tx_params)
  return C.detectNetwork().then(function () {
    return new Promise(function (accept, reject) {
      var callback = function (error, result) {
        if (error != null) {
          reject(error)
        } else {
          accept(result)
        }
      }
      args.push(tx_params, callback)
      fn.apply(instance.contract, args)
    })
  })
}
```

this type of data I am getting in `alert(contractInstance.machineList);`

So, how can we get array values in side JS without making explicit getter function inside solidity rather to call in built in getter function which is provided by solidity for state variable ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get dynamic array like this : **uint256[] public machineList** by creating a contract getter function.

```
function getMachineList () external returns (uint256[]){
return machineList
}
```

note the external modifier i added, in this kind of functions where you are returning a dynamically sized array the external modifier is mandatory. it also makes the function only callable from the exterior of the contract which is exactly what we want here.

An other thing is that you are using **truffle** to call contract functions. When using truffle you need to call a **promise** (or a callback)  after the name of the function :

```
AssetContract.deployed().then(function (contractInstance) {

  contractInstance.getMachineList.
  call(**arguments if any**,{ from:**address**, gas: 300000 }).then(
    data => {
      var MachineList = data;
      alert(MachineList);
    }
  )

})
```

**Note:** whenu sing truffle you add the `.call()` if you are just calling functions that read and return variables as if it will not alter state variables (change/add existing/new value).

Comment: Yes, actually your solution is correct, I have already make the getter function which returning that array. and also I got the proper values in side the js file like this.    contractInstance.getMachineList.call().then(function(machineId) { 
  
    var temp = contractInstance.machineList;
    alert(temp);
 
      });

Comment: But the point I didn't get is that if we are returning an array then why I got the output like this : 111, 112, 113,114,115,116 instead of array object.

Comment: Actually later on I got that in solidity in built getters are provided that's why I have tried out solution which is there in question

Comment: yes, public state variables have getters created automatically, but i am not sure that you can call get on a public dynamic array and still get the values you need. But the external getter function i mentioned returns the correct values and format, if you can post more code and output then i can help clarrify.

Comment: Actually, I have initialized 2 array for that and I want that array values inside web application drop down box. So, that is working. But now if we select some values from both of that drop down box then I want to do the mapping of both that selected values.

Comment: For that, I have create this function inside smart contract :



function allocate(uint256 machineId,uint256 userId) public returns (bool){
    machineAllocs[machineId] = userId;
    //return machineAllocs[machineId];
    
    if( machineAllocs[machineId] == 0 ) {
      machineAllocs[machineId] = userId;
      return true;
    }else {
      return false;
     }  
    
  }

But when I call this function from js then it retruns [object object]. I don't know how to do it further.

Comment: In contrat development you can't call a function that alters state variables and return value. if a function alters state it will be considered as a transaction and will not return value, instead it will return the transaction receipt. when using truffle or web3 there is difference between the two ways of calling functions. The method you called form your contract does alter state variable as it adds new data to the smart contract, so it will not return any value even if you mention the `return` in your code.

Comment: Ok, if I will set true or false value to some state variable then I will get the value of that variable from getter function that boolean variable. So, will that work or not?

Comment: Yes it should work, but it is just not like java where you can modify a state variable and return value in the same function, reading and writing should be in seperate functions.

Comment: Means I can change the value of mapping in one function and returning it in another function. Will that work ?

Comment: see I have two functions in contract : 

function getMachineAllocs(uint256 machineId) view public returns (uint256) {
   return machineAllocs[machineId]; 
  }

  function allocate(uint256 machineId,uint256 userId) public {
    machineAllocs[machineId] = userId;
    
    
  }


And I calling them like this in js file : 
contractInstance.allocate(parseInt(machineId), parseInt(userId),{gas: 140000, from: web3.eth.accounts[0]}).then(function() {
return contractInstance.getBoolean.call(parseInt(machineId)).then(function(c) and print c,it returns 0 value. why is that so ?

Answer (score 0):

You can't access to the entire array without specifying the getter. You can still call the build in function provided by the `public` state variable but you need to provide the index of the array to get its value.

Indeed, your ABI for the provided array would be something like this

```
{
    "constant": true,
    "inputs": [
        {
            "name": "",
            "type": "uint256"
        }
    ],
    "name": "machineList",
    "outputs": [
        {
            "name": "",
            "type": "uint256"
        }
    ],
    "payable": false,
    "stateMutability": "view",
    "type": "function"
}
```

an input is expected, and is the index of the element of the array that you want to read.

Comment: Yes, if we are providing index then it is returning [object Promise] type of value.